# Is there a way to customize this mini hovering toolbar?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

[image: http://i.imgur.com/S5C2x.png]

I want to add the strike-through icon there

Comment: The likely place is File -> Options. But I could only find options to change the ribbon along the top.

So Im guessing its not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in Office 2007, it seems that the Mini Toolbar is not customizable by users.

From [here](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=86712):

> Q: Within Word I want to edit or change the commands in the hovering mini
>   toolbar, i.e. I would like to add an UNDERLINE feature; Multilevel
>   List  feature; and more Align Text options.

```
This mini toolbar is not user-customizable.
-- 
Suzanne S. Barnhill
Microsoft MVP (Word)
Words into Type
Fairhope, Alabama USA
Word MVP FAQ site: http://word.mvps.org
```

From [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-office-word/165296-can-i-customize-word-2007s-mini-toolbar.html):

```
If you're referring to the toolbar that displays
when you hover on selected text the short answer is no. Search this group &
you will find reference to 3rd-party add-ins as well as means by which to
import toolbars from earlier versions of Word. Whether any provide
customizing of the mini I can't recall.
--
Regards |:>)
Bob Jones
[MVP] Office:Mac
```

and

```
Sadly, it is not customizable. But you do know, don't you, that there are
built-in keyboard shortcuts for all but one of the commands you list?

Underline: Ctrl+U
Cut: Ctrl+X
Copy: Ctrl+C
Paste: Ctrl+V
Align Left: Ctrl+L
Align Right: Ctrl+R
Justify: Ctrl+J
(and Center: Ctrl+E)

--
Suzanne S. Barnhill
Microsoft MVP (Word)
Words into Type
Fairhope, Alabama USA
Word MVP FAQ site: http://word.mvps.org
```

Comment: +1: keyboard short cuts.  Or add it to the Quick access bar, which are  accessible with Alt+ 1,2,3,4 . . .

Comment: hit Ctrl+Space to remove the formatting and convert the selection into plain text.